# separate searches in windows in VIM

Tags: search, vim, split

When I split VIM to show me a few files or a different parts of the same file, is there any way for me to have one search in one window and a different search in another one?  For instance, I'd like the upper window to have the search pattern `foo` and the lower window to have the search pattern `bar`.

The active search pattern affects what is highlighted when using search highlighting, and it is pretty annoying when I have `foo` highlighted in the upper window, and then I switch to the lower window and search for `bar`, and `foo` stops being highlighted in the upper window.

**Edit:**  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704434/is-there-any-way-to-highlight-multiple-searches-in-gvim) seems to be related, though I'm not sure it's an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=479) script for highlighting multiple search patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Canopus's answer is probably the nicest way to do it if you're using this often, but if you want to do it with a vanilla vim install (or more to the point, without installing any plugins), you can simply do:

```
:call matchadd('Search', 'foo')
:call matchadd('Search', 'bar')
```

You can then clear all matches with

```
:call clearmatches()
```

There are also ways of being more fussy about what you clear (with `:call matchdelete(...)`) by saving the output of matchadd to a variable.  You can read more about this in `:help matchadd()` and `:help matchdelete()`

If you're not using too complicated a syntax file (and specifically, not using the rainbow.vim highlighting), you can probably also do it with:

```
:syn keyword Search foo
:syn keyword Search bar
```

and clear it with

```
:syn clear Search
```

The only possible advantage of this that I can think of is that if there are a *lot* of matches that you're trying to highlight, a `keyword` highlight is a lot quicker than a `match` highlight (as the latter uses a regular expression search).  You can still do a `syn keyword` match if you're using rainbow.vim, but the command is much more complicated.