# Vim highlight a list of words

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I need to highlight a list of words in vim, preferably the words should be defined in a file. A bit like spell checking. I have been looking at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words but it requires that I define each word as a new position and does not support storing the words to a file (though they are storable).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use the `:match` command.

```
:match Todo /word1/
```

The first parameter of the command is the highlight-group (to see all available groups `:highlight`). The second parameter is a search pattern.

You can put these in any file and load it via `:source`.

Another way is to change the regular expression (thx @zpon):

```
:match Todo /word1\|word2\|word3/
```

If you want to highlight them differently:

```
:match Todo /word1/
:2match Error /word2/
:3match Title /word3/
```

Comment: When I add more than one line to file it is only the last line that is highlighted

Comment: Figured it out, :match VisualNOS /word1\|word2\|word3/

Comment: You have the `:match`, `:2match` and `:3match` commands to do that, and therefore you can store three patterns. But you also can use `:call matchadd()` (`:help matchadd()`).

Answer (score 23):

I would recommend you use `syn keyword` for this.  There are other options like `:match` as suggested by [michael.kebe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189058/michael-kebe) and `syn match` etc, but these are all based on regular expression matches.  The disadvantage of this is that as the number of words that you want to match increases, the speed of Vim decreases.  Keyword matches are **much** faster.  You can also easily define multiple keywords on a line (although there is a limit of about 512 characters on a line, if memory serves me correctly).

```
syn keyword Todo word1 word2 word3
syn keyword Todo word4
syn keyword Todo word5
```

Put these lines in any file and `:source` it or dump it in your `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` for it to be `source`d automatically for all C files (pick your syntax file for the file type you're interested in).

As with [michael.kebe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189058/michael-kebe)'s answer, the first parameter (`Todo` in this case) is the highlight group.  You can make up your own group if you want to and define the highlighting:

```
syn keyword MyHighlightGroup word6 word7
" Then EITHER (define your own colour scheme):
hi MyGroupName guifg=Blue ctermfg=Blue term=bold
" OR (make the colour scheme match an existing one):
hi link MyGroupName Todo
```

Comment: Is there any constraints on the syn keyword method? I does not seem to have any effect on one of my tex files, but on all other files

Comment: The only constraints I know of are that the characters in the word must all be keyword characters (i.e. no `:` or other symbols) and that you can't use one of the vim special syntax-related option keywords (`contained` etc).  For those I'd use `syn match MyHighlightGroup /\<contained\>/` or whatever.

Comment: That's strange, I have only used normal words like "that" and "there"

Comment: It's possible that the paragraph is already highlighted (but as Normal text).  Try using this: `map <F3> :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name") . '> trans<' . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),0),"name") . "> lo<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"name") . ">" . " FG:" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"fg#") . " BG:" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"bg#")<CR>`  put the cursor on the word and press F3.  If there's anything in the angle brackets, you'll have to add `containedin=GroupName` to the syntax keyword lines.

Comment: Alternatively, post a complete example file (text can just be lorem ipsum if you like) and I'll figure out how to get it working.

Comment: The problem seems to be with some LaTeX commands. Everything before \section (or \subsection) isn't affected by the keyword command.

Answer (score -1):

:match Todo /\<\(word1\|word2\|word3\)\>/