# Highlight Matching Pair Error

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, parentheses

This is the error I get when I try to insert parentheses or braces:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>36_Highlight_Matching_Pair: line  140: E801: ID already taken: 3
```

It started occurring after I added the following code to `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`

```
hi WhiteOnMagenta term=standout,bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=Magenta
3match WhiteOnMagenta /TEST/
```

I think it's because of a conflict between my match and something in `matchparen.vim`. The error disappears once I comment out the lines above in my syntax file or if I delete the matchparen plugin file.

I want to keep the matchparen plugin because I like being able to have my parentheses underlined when my cursor is on one of them. I also like using `:match` instead of `syn keyword` as shown in [Vim highlight a list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162664/vim-highlight-a-list-of-words) because `:match` still highlights the keyword even if it's used in a comment (and `syn keyword` does not)

Any solution where I can still have underlined parentheses and highlighted keywords (even when used in a comment) will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm still not sure what the problem was, but I fixed it by changing all of my `match` to `matchadd` like so

Original:

```
hi WhiteOnMagenta term=standout,bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=Magenta
3match WhiteOnMagenta /TEST/
```

New (and better):

```
hi WhiteOnMagenta term=standout,bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=Magenta
let m = matchadd("WhiteOnMagenta", "TEST")
```