# How to write a vim function to search multiple strings (when I call a function) and highlight all strings (so that I use n/N to move)

Tags: vim

I want to call this function (using my mapping) and highlight all strings so that I can use n/N to navigate.

Here is my code and mapping for this function but not able to make it work.

```
  function! FindAll(...)
     let srchstr =  ""   
     let list = split(a:000[0], ' ')
     let lenth = len(list)
     for item in list
         let lenth = lenth - 1
         if lenth != 0
             let srchstr .= item."\\\|"
         else
             let srchstr .= item
         endif
     endfor

     "echo srchstr

     exec 'normal! /' . srchstr . "\<CR>"
  endfunction
```

Then I am using this mapping to call it :

```
noremap <silent> ,fa  :call FindAll(input("Please Give Separate Strings :"))<CR>
```

And this is how I am giving input strings when I called it.

```
Please Give Separate Strings :One Two Three
```

Comment: Seraching muliple words is already supported and the `n` and `N` works too. Just try `/\vkeyword1|keyword2|keyword3` Previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704434/is-there-any-way-to-highlight-multiple-searches-in-gvim

Comment: Thanks @Harish, Yes I can use n/N if I do it manually but I want it using a function.  So that if I just give strings separated by space it automatically add | in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're struggling with [`:help function-search-undo`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#function-search-undo):

> The last used search pattern and the redo command "." will not be changed by the function.

This makes your search command ineffective within the `FindAll()` function.

#### Additional critique

- `input()` will always return a single String; there's no need for the variable arguments `(...)` handling.
- Your `for` loop can be replaced by `join()`.
- Instead of `:normal! /`, you can just assign to `@/`, the last search pattern register ([`:help quote/`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote%2F)).
- Your mapping doesn't use the visual selection or pending operator, so better just define it for *normal mode*.

#### Fixes

To be able to modify the search pattern, either have the function return it, or (based on the suggested simplifications above) do the whole processing inline. It's just a `split` - `join` combination now:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,fa :let @/ =
\ join(split(input("Please Give Separate Strings :"), ' '), '\<Bar>')<CR>
```

Actually, we can just exchange every space character with the regular expression branch item `\|`:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,fa :let @/ =
\ substitute(input("Please Give Separate Strings :"), ' ', '\\<Bar>', 'g')<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ingo Karkat, I tried with all your suggestions one by one: 1) I replaced normal! with let @/ =, it is working fine. 

Then I tried with these two other mapping one with **join-split** and other **substitute**. 
I found two issues.

i) If strings are separated with more than one white spaces ii) If initially, we have space. 
I fixed these issue in **join-split** using '\W\+' 
but I was not able to fix (ii) issue even after using '\s\+' in **substitute**.

Comment: Hi @Ingo Karkat can you suggest me something to clear the vim command line just after calling this mapping or even calling my fucntion. Wherever it is possible I'll use that.

Comment: The same issue I fixed in split call in **FindAll** function also.

Comment: Yes, `\s\+` will match one or more whitespace. It should work with both `split()` and `substitute()` (if you embed them inside single quotes, or double the backslashes).

Comment: You can clear the command-line by using `<Bar>echo "\r"<Bar>echo<CR>` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, It is working now. I've used **echo "\r"** twice as last lines in my function.